# Как в ThreadPool проверить, что все потоки завершены

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Как в пуле потоков проверить, что все фоновые потоки завершены, а после этого запускать уже другую задачу, которая идет в основном потоке?

Comment: вот тут ответ устроит? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490702/how-to-know-if-all-the-thread-pools-thread-are-already-done-with-its-tasks

Comment: Все таски в тредах завершены, только ;)

Comment: Переходите на Task'и. В TPL подобные задачи решаются намного проще.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак. Прежде всего, потоки пула никогда не завершаются (на то он и пул).

Наверное, вам нужно определить что завершились все поставленные вами задачи. Тут выход прост - запоминайте поставленные задачи и ждите завершения конкретно их.

Если используемое вами API не позволяет дождаться окончания поставленной задачи - переходите на другое API.

К примеру, с использованием `Task` это делается так:

```
var a = Task.Run(() => ... );
var b = FooAsync(...);
var c = StartNewTask(...);

// ...

Task.WaitAll(a,b,c);
```

Comment: Мне тогда в цикле создавать в массиве Task, а потом этому массиву просто Task.WaitAll(task)?

Comment: @AsmaRod да, так тоже можно